# C# for visual studio 2010 excel development

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, excel-2007

I have created an excel 2007 workbook that has hidden worksheets in.  There is one worksheet unhidden that has commands buttons with each worksheet name on each command button.  When a command button is clicked, the hidden worksheet should be made visible and the focus should be placed on that worksheet.  The code below returns this error:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or
>   property 'Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.WorksheetBase.Visible get'

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;

namespace TestProj
{
    public partial class Sheet17
    {
        private void Sheet17_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void Sheet17_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        #region VSTO Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InternalStartup()
        {
            this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
            this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(this.Sheet17_Startup);
            this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(this.Sheet17_Shutdown);

        }

        #endregion

        private void checkedListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Sheet5 How = new Sheet5();
            How.Visible = Excel.XlSheetVisibility.xlSheetVisible;
        }

    }
}
```

Can someone please help me with this error?

Comment: Are you sure sheet5 is created?

Comment: Yes, it is showing in visual studio as 'Sheet5.cs (how)'

Comment: Have you declared: new Excel.Application(); somewhere?  I think that is your problem.

Comment: So you have a `Sheet5.cs` file in your Visual Studio ?

Comment: No, I don't see that anywhere.  The code that is shown was auto generated within visual studio when I created the project.                                                             using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;

Comment: Update it on question for these codes and maybe more codes..

Comment: It seems that you're trying to access a non static field from a type. You should access non static fields from instances of a type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use like this;

```
Sheet5 mySheet = new Sheet5();
mySheet.Visible = Excel.XlSheetVisibility.xlSheetVisible;
```

or make your `Sheet5` class `static`. You can't access to your `non-static` class without any create an instance of this class.

Read it from [`MSDN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx).

Comment: when I tried your suggestion this is the error that was returned - Error: 'TestProj.Sheet5' doest not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments.

Comment: private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Sheet5 How = new Sheet5();
            How.Visible = Excel.XlSheetVisibility.xlSheetVisible;
        }

Comment: What is exactly `Sheet5` then ?

Comment: it is just a worksheet with instructions on it and it is named 'How'

Comment: Sure...I apologize for the confusion

Comment: @Soner...I have modified my original question and posted all of the code that I have

Comment: @dsal So you don't have a `Sheet5` class, how expect to create an instance of it with `Sheet5 How = new Sheet5();` ? It is imposible.

Comment: Please tell me how to make the class so that the instance can be created?

Comment: I think your problem isn't about the code, It is about Object Orianted Programming http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming

Comment: @Soner...I have modified my code to declare 'Sheet5' as a class.  Now I am getting a new error - 'TestProj.Sheet17.Sheet5' does not contain a definition for 'Visible' and no extension method 'Visible' accepting a first argument of type 'TestProj.Sheet17.Sheet5' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)